# My jupyter notebook doesn't warn to use the latest numpy version

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, conda

I am using a conda virtual env and i already upgraded numpy to 1.22. In my notebook it still uses 1.19.

[image]

why isn't it using 1.22?

Also when i open the venv in Python with a CLI:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.22.4'
```

Comment: Your CLI is probably using a different Python installation. Upgrading a module in one doesn't upgrade it in all. Conda typically does its own Python installation and ignores what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Jupyter from a base environment or from the new environment?  If you are launching Jupyter from a different environment, you need to switch kernels to the new environment.

There are several ways to check which kernel you are using, typically:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

If the path is not in the correct environment, you can change by selecting the Kernel drop-menu > "Change Kernel..."

If the kernel you want to use does not appear there, you need to install `ipykernel`.

```
conda install --name <env name> ipykernel
```

How did you install the new version of numpy?  For a Conda environment, you should use Conda.  If you used PIP, it may be in an entirely different location/environment.

You can check the difference by running the following in Jupyter and the Python REPL:

```
import numpy as np
np.__file__
```